# Healthy older cat had a scratch that healed but now hasn't eaten for days

Tags: cats, health

My cat is a healthy male, about 14 years old. He is not obese, eats holistic food, including wet food.

I noticed, before the eating issue that he had some pus in the corner of his eye. I looked at it as close as I could, didn't see anything but I cleaned it with a moist cotton ball. A little later, I checked and it looked worse and a little bloody. I use colloidal silver all the time. It works great for cleaning pet wounds. I sprayed colloidal silver on a cotton ball and cleaned it really well and gently.

But I noticed a scratch on his upper eye lid. There was a tinge of pink on the cotton ball. The next day I checked it again and it appeared that he had an abscess that was draining below his lower lid. I cleaned it several times during the day. Within two days it has completely cleared up.

The problem is that he hasn't eaten at all in about 5 days. I have been making it easy for him to get water by always keeping a bowl beside him so he doesn't have to go far. I am worried, so I have made him some organic broth to get some nutrients in him. He is not interested but I have been dropper feeding him with it. He is lethargic. I had to work the past three days and could not get him to the vet. There are no visible signs of anything wrong.

I am worried about him!

Comment: Not eating could be any of a number of serious illnesses, including kidney failure, especially at an advanced age. Make time to get him to the vet? There may be an after-hours clinic somewhere. You may have a friend who could take him in for you.

Comment: Definitely go to a vet ASAP. The abscess may appear healed on the surface, but infection can remain under the skin.

Answer (score 1):

Get to a vet. It sounds like your cat has an infection. It may be healed on the surface but apparently not internally. Five days is a long time for an animal, especially a small one, to go without food or water. You may now be running into an issue of dehydration. Definitely go straight to the vet. I hope everything goes well for your kitty!